# In tensorflow fit function, I am getting this error: TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: deep-learning

in a cat and dog classification problem

I got an error in
cnn.fit(training_set, validation_data = test_set, batch_size=32, epochs = 30)

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-ee0b03f0e8d6> in <module>
      1 # training training set and evaluate test set
----> 2 cnn.fit(training_set, validation_data = test_set, batch_size=32, epochs = 30)

~\anaconda\envs\TF\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1145           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1146           model=self,
-> 1147           steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
   1148 
   1149       # Container that configures and calls `tf.keras.Callback`s.

~\anaconda\envs\TF\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in get_data_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1362   if getattr(kwargs["model"], "_cluster_coordinator", None):
   1363     return _ClusterCoordinatorDataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
-> 1364   return DataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
   1365 
   1366 

~\anaconda\envs\TF\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution, distribute)
   1164         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1165         distribution_strategy=ds_context.get_strategy(),
-> 1166         model=model)
   1167 
   1168     strategy = ds_context.get_strategy()

~\anaconda\envs\TF\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, shuffle, workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size, model, **kwargs)
    937         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    938         model=model,
--> 939         **kwargs)
    940 
    941   @staticmethod

~\anaconda\envs\TF\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size, model, **kwargs)
    807     # Since we have to know the dtype of the python generator when we build the
    808     # dataset, we have to look at a batch to infer the structure.
--> 809     peek, x = self._peek_and_restore(x)
    810     peek = self._standardize_batch(peek)
    811     peek = _process_tensorlike(peek)

~\anaconda\envs\TF\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in _peek_and_restore(x)
    941   @staticmethod
    942   def _peek_and_restore(x):
--> 943     return x[0], x
    944 
    945   def _handle_multiprocessing(self, x, workers, use_multiprocessing,

~\anaconda\envs\TF\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
     63         index_array = self.index_array[self.batch_size * idx:
     64                                        self.batch_size * (idx + 1)]
---> 65         return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
     66 
     67     def __len__(self):

~\anaconda\envs\TF\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array)
    229                            target_size=self.target_size,
    230                            interpolation=self.interpolation)
--> 231             x = img_to_array(img, data_format=self.data_format)
    232             # Pillow images should be closed after `load_img`,
    233             # but not PIL images.

~\anaconda\envs\TF\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py in img_to_array(img, data_format, dtype)
    307     # or (channel, height, width)
    308     # but original PIL image has format (width, height, channel)
--> 309     x = np.asarray(img, dtype=dtype)
    310     if len(x.shape) == 3:
    311         if data_format == 'channels_first':

~\anaconda\envs\TF\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81       UPDATEIFCOPY : False
     82 
---> 83     >>> y = np.require(x, dtype=np.float32, requirements=['A', 'O', 'W', 'F'])
     84     >>> y.flags
     85       C_CONTIGUOUS : False

TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I think there is some problem with numpy or with pillow but I am not sure, I am using tensorflow = 2.5.0 and numpy = 1.21.0, cuda = 11.0 please check if I am using the right version or there can be problem in cuda version

Answer (score 1):

I am having he same question, my env is cuda 10.1 tensorflow 1.13.1 numpy 1.21.0, I think maybe something wrong with numpy, However I tested it , but not right. I search again and found maybe there is something wrong with pillow, I fixed it by pip install pillow==8.2.0
seems somethings wrong with pillow pack